# multiply two arrays of different size along joined common axis (like Cartesian product)

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I am looking for a fast way to multiply two arrays (let's start with two matrices) to create higher dimensional array, but join the matrices along one axis.

Example:

```
A <- array(dim=c(4,3),0)
A[1:2,2] <- 0.5
A[,3][] <- 0.5

> A
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0  0.5  0.5
#[2,]    0  0.5  0.5
#[3,]    0  0.0  0.5
#[4,]    0  0.0  0.5

B <- B <- array(dim=c(10,3),rnorm(n=30))

> B
 #            [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
 #[1,] -0.94656774  0.70659483  0.34509323
 #[2,]  0.58387120  1.16334931  1.10026658
 #[3,] -0.07538463  0.88417903  0.01772409
 #[4,] -0.64006957  0.16655132 -0.50860357
 #[5,] -0.74535755 -0.65954998  0.77425534
 #[6,]  1.67392684  0.99055556 -0.02527703
 #[7,]  0.41809160  0.97167365  0.18338053
 #[8,] -2.10664048 -0.06923934 -2.64993861
 #[9,]  0.13877915  0.17980610 -1.00056096
 #[10,] -1.18685229  0.42634576  2.23949858
```

The result should be a 3d array with the following dimensions:

```
C <- array(dim=c(10,3,4))
```

Whereas the "3" dimension is joint between A and B.

so that

```
> C[1,,]
 #            [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
 #[1,]           0  0.35329741  0.17254661
 #[2,]           0  0.35329741  0.17254661
 #[3,]           0           0  0.17254661
 #[4,]           0           0  0.17254661
```

The way I have found is to "inflate" and aperm A and B so that they match the dimensions of C and a simple `A*B` would work. But this doesn't feel right and takes way too long in practice.

Thanks

---

### EDIT

In response to Nicola's answer, and further research, inflating both arrays to match dimensions and do a simple A*B seems the way to go.

For completeness here my method how I inflate:

```
B <- array(dim=c(10,100),rnorm(n=10*100)) # small array
A <- array(dim=c(10,100,10000)) # creating empty big array
A[] <- B # "inflate" B into A.
```

Now I wonder how this could be done more efficient.
But maybe worth a new post?

Thanks

[Reference to new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33877410/inflate-array-add-additional-dimension-with-copies-of-itself)

Comment: Had the same problem for a project involving this kind of multiplications. I guess your way is right (it's what I used at first). Of course you need just one `aperm`, after inflating both `A` and `B`. However, it involves a lot of overhead. Eventually, I decided to write a C function doing this task (which can be a bit annoying, but definitely doable).

Comment: Thanks Nicola, It seems inflating the arrays to the higher dimensions wasn't a bad idea (see post edit). Can you tell whether you found a faster way to achieve the inflation step? Feel free to give it as an "answer" and I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: I guess you are doing things right. The last two lines can be merged into one: `A <- array(B,dim=c(10,100,10000))`.