# Inflate array (add additional dimension with copies of itself)

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array

I need to perform basic calculations on arrays of different dimensionality.

The recommended solution seems to be to inflate all arrays to match size.

For example, Array B with dimension 10x100. And array C with dimension 10x10000. The result (e.g. by multiplication) should be an array D of size 10x100x10000.

Therefore I would "inflate" B by the "10000" dimension, and C by the "100" dimension and simply do B*C.

Now, what is the best (fastest) way to achieve this inflation?

A slow method illustrating the desired outcome:

```
B <- array(dim=c(10,100),rnorm(n=10*100)) # small array
A <- array(dim=c(10,100,10000)) # creating empty big array
A[] <- B # "inflate" B into A, creating 10'000 copies of B
```

Ideas?

### Idea 1

Just tried this, about 3x faster:

```
A <- rep(B,10000)
dim(A) <- c(10,100,10000)
```

Still searching..

[Reference to original request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784656/multiply-two-arrays-of-different-size-along-joined-common-axis-like-cartesian-p)

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but you can probably rely on recycling instead.

Comment: With recycling you mean, that it starts from position[1,1,1] again when the end is reached? This works if using against a vector, but not with arrays. Or did I misunderstand your suggestion?

Comment: Well, you could make your arrays vectors (that's what they are internally anyway), do the multiplication and add the dimensions attribute again afterwards. You might need to use `aperm` to get this right, but that's the approach I would use.

Comment: Thanks, just tried with `A <- c(B)` with redim A and it was about the same speed as initial idea `A[] <- B`. It seems `rep()` is the best answer so far. Not sure why.